# Magento 2.2.6 Anchor setting (ON / OFF) does not work in category setting

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

Magento 2.2.6 Anchor setting (ON / OFF) does not work in category setting.

Please check the screenshot below.

[image]

I have not found a solution.

Could you please help me?

nice to meet you.

Comment: does the toggling of button work?

Comment: Yes. It will turn green when saved in the on state.

Comment: then what was the problem? its not clear.

Comment: Detailed search will continue to be output to category page.
I want to hide it, so I want to use the Anchor.

Answer (score 0):

Try Reindexing manually and clear cache

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindexall
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: I tried that procedure already.

Comment: Do you have any custom module installed for category page?

Comment: Also try to use it in "all store view" instead of using specific store view.. then see if it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
However, it is a but a substitution.

Remove the filter navigation from the back end with custom layout for each category.

```
<referenceContainer name="catalog.leftnav" remove="true" />
```

[image]

Probably, it seems to be a malfunction that exists from the beginning of Magento 2.
The following is a problem that has been submitted to the Magento 2 project.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7765