# Apply product to parent and child categories on import

Tags: magento2, import, magento2.2.2, import-products, magento2.2.7

I am trying to import products into `v2.2.7`. Many products have many categories like:

`Default Category/A1/A2/A3, Default Category/B1/B2/B3`

When i check the product configuration, the product only has `A3` and `B3` checked as categories when it should have all the following categories checked for the product:

```
Default Category
Default Category/A1
Default Category/A1/A2
Default Category/A1/A2/A3

Default Category/B1
Default Category/B1/B2
Default Category/B1/B2/B3
```

I even tried sending the categories in like the following hoping it would add each of them as a category:

```
Default Category/A1,Default Category/A1/A2,Default Category/A1/A2/A3,Default Category/B1,Default Category/B1/B2,Default Category/B1/B2/B3
```

But that resulted in the following error:

```
1. Category " has not been created. URL key for specified store already exists. in row(s): 1
General system exception happened
Additional data:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`magento`.`catalog_category_product`, CONSTRAINT `CAT_CTGR_PRD_CTGR_ID_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_category_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE), query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_category_product` (`product_id`,`category_id`,`position`) VALUES (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `product_id` = VALUES(`product_id`), `category_id` = VALUES(`category_id`)
```

And when i go to categories, I see it's created "Default Category" again instead of importing to the existing root "Default Category"! And it also created `A1` and `B1` in the others inside the root "Default Category".

test csv:

```
sku,store_view_code,attribute_set_code,product_type,categories,product_websites,name,description,short_description,weight,product_online,tax_class_name,visibility,price,special_price,special_price_from_date,special_price_to_date,url_key,meta_title,meta_keywords,meta_description,created_at,updated_at,new_from_date,new_to_date,display_product_options_in,map_price,msrp_price,map_enabled,gift_message_available,custom_design,custom_design_from,custom_design_to,custom_layout_update,page_layout,product_options_container,msrp_display_actual_price_type,country_of_manufacture,additional_attributes,qty,out_of_stock_qty,use_config_min_qty,is_qty_decimal,allow_backorders,use_config_backorders,min_cart_qty,use_config_min_sale_qty,max_cart_qty,use_config_max_sale_qty,is_in_stock,notify_on_stock_below,use_config_notify_stock_qty,manage_stock,use_config_manage_stock,use_config_qty_increments,qty_increments,use_config_enable_qty_inc,enable_qty_increments,is_decimal_divided,website_id,deferred_stock_update,use_config_deferred_stock_update,related_skus,crosssell_skus,upsell_skus,hide_from_product_page,custom_options,bundle_price_type,bundle_sku_type,bundle_price_view,bundle_weight_type,bundle_values,associated_skus
qqqq,,Default,simple,"Default Category/A1, Default Category/A1/A2, Default Category/A1/A2/A3",base,Cool sock,,test,1,1,Taxable Goods,"Catalog, Search",0,,,,test11,test meta title,,test meta description,,,,,Block after Info Column,,999,,,,,,,,,Use config,,"has_options=0,quantity_and_stock_status=In Stock,required_options=0",17,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,7,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Below is what my category directory looks like after the failure (Before test, I deleted all categories and sub-categories except "Default Category" since trying the import with categories already created still broke).

```
Default Category (0)
  A1 (0)
Default Category (0)
```

Maybe i shouldn't tell it the category belongs in `Default Category`? Nope, that just creates another root category and even then it doesn't check all categories. Here is test CSV:

```
sku,store_view_code,attribute_set_code,product_type,categories,product_websites,name,description,short_description,weight,product_online,tax_class_name,visibility,price,special_price,special_price_from_date,special_price_to_date,url_key,meta_title,meta_keywords,meta_description,created_at,updated_at,new_from_date,new_to_date,display_product_options_in,map_price,msrp_price,map_enabled,gift_message_available,custom_design,custom_design_from,custom_design_to,custom_layout_update,page_layout,product_options_container,msrp_display_actual_price_type,country_of_manufacture,additional_attributes,qty,out_of_stock_qty,use_config_min_qty,is_qty_decimal,allow_backorders,use_config_backorders,min_cart_qty,use_config_min_sale_qty,max_cart_qty,use_config_max_sale_qty,is_in_stock,notify_on_stock_below,use_config_notify_stock_qty,manage_stock,use_config_manage_stock,use_config_qty_increments,qty_increments,use_config_enable_qty_inc,enable_qty_increments,is_decimal_divided,website_id,deferred_stock_update,use_config_deferred_stock_update,related_skus,crosssell_skus,upsell_skus,hide_from_product_page,custom_options,bundle_price_type,bundle_sku_type,bundle_price_view,bundle_weight_type,bundle_values,associated_skus
qqqq,,Default,simple,"A1, A1/A2, A1/A2/A3",base,Cool sock,,test,1,1,Taxable Goods,"Catalog, Search",0,,,,test11,test meta title,,test meta description,,,,,Block after Info Column,,999,,,,,,,,,Use config,,"has_options=0,quantity_and_stock_status=In Stock,required_options=0",17,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,7,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Which results in the following category structure:
[image]

What? two `A1`'s? And didn't even check the `A1` that is the parent of the checked `A2`.

How can i import products and make the product appear in the parent category as well as sub-categories instead of only the last child category?

Answer (score 0):

Both test `csv` examples in the post have spaces after the comma in the categories. Brutal. Not sure why Magento doesn't `trim` white-space off beginning and end of field on import.

Try this:

```
sku,store_view_code,attribute_set_code,product_type,categories,product_websites,name,description,short_description,weight,product_online,tax_class_name,visibility,price,special_price,special_price_from_date,special_price_to_date,url_key,meta_title,meta_keywords,meta_description,created_at,updated_at,new_from_date,new_to_date,display_product_options_in,map_price,msrp_price,map_enabled,gift_message_available,custom_design,custom_design_from,custom_design_to,custom_layout_update,page_layout,product_options_container,msrp_display_actual_price_type,country_of_manufacture,additional_attributes,qty,out_of_stock_qty,use_config_min_qty,is_qty_decimal,allow_backorders,use_config_backorders,min_cart_qty,use_config_min_sale_qty,max_cart_qty,use_config_max_sale_qty,is_in_stock,notify_on_stock_below,use_config_notify_stock_qty,manage_stock,use_config_manage_stock,use_config_qty_increments,qty_increments,use_config_enable_qty_inc,enable_qty_increments,is_decimal_divided,website_id,deferred_stock_update,use_config_deferred_stock_update,related_skus,crosssell_skus,upsell_skus,hide_from_product_page,custom_options,bundle_price_type,bundle_sku_type,bundle_price_view,bundle_weight_type,bundle_values,associated_skus
qqqq,,Default,simple,"Default Category/A1,Default Category/A1/A2,Default Category/A1/A2/A3",base,Cool sock,,test,1,1,Taxable Goods,"Catalog, Search",0,,,,test11,test meta title,,test meta description,,,,,Block after Info Column,,999,,,,,,,,,Use config,,"has_options=0,quantity_and_stock_status=In Stock,required_options=0",17,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,7,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Results looking at categories in that product:
[image]

Something else to look into if you want products to show up in parent category is checking **Catalog > Categories > [your category] > Display Settings > Anchor = Yes**. Do this for each of the categories that you want to inherit/show it's child category products .

Note that setting it to **No** has the side affect of [removing the category "layered navigation"](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/categories-display-settings.html) at that level. To get around this, setup attributes that match your categories and apply them to your products during on-boarding so you have more control over the way things show up.

Threads related to second idea:
[Parent category is showing products in subcategories, even though product was not assigned to parent category](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/parent-category-is-showing-products-in-subcategories-even-though-product-was-no)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22990622/magento-stop-child-products-showing-in-anchor-category

[Magento 2.2.6 Anchor setting (ON / OFF) does not work in category setting](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/246768/magento-2-2-6-anchor-setting-on-off-does-not-work-in-category-setting)